# Control argument names in reactivePlot in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Drawing from the question [select a variable from drop-down and pass it as an argument in reactivePlot in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635673/select-a-variable-from-drop-down-and-pass-it-as-an-argument-in-reactiveplot-in-r)

and @Jdbaba answer, I was wondering if it was possible to control the name of variables we want to display.

In @Jdbaba example, he uses

```
dataset <- diamonds
... 
selectInput('x','X',names(dataset))
```

I would like to know if I could pass my own variable names 
like this for example

```
newnames = paste('abc', 1:10)
....
selectInput('x','X', list( newnames = names(dataset)) )
```

Any thoughts ?

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

newnames = paste('abc', 1:10)

## Define UI for miles per gallon application

dataset <- diamonds

title <- "Diamonds 
data Analysis"

## Define UI for application that plots random distributions

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel(title),

  sidebarPanel (

sliderInput('sampleSize','Sample Size', min=1, max=nrow(dataset),
            value=min(1000,nrow(dataset)),
            step=500,
            round=0),
#################
# Question here  
#################
selectInput('x','X', list( newnames = names(dataset)) ),
selectInput('y','Y', names(dataset), names(dataset)[[2]]),

selectInput('color','Color',c('None',names(dataset))),

selectInput('shape','Shape',c('None',names(dataset))),

checkboxInput('jitter','Jitter'),
checkboxInput('smooth','Smooth'),

selectInput('facet_col','Facet Column',
            c(None='.',names(dataset))),

selectInput('facet_row','Facet Row',
            c(None='.',names(dataset)))

  ),

  ## Show a plot of the generated distribution

  mainPanel(plotOutput('plot',height="700px"))

  )
)
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

## Define server logic required to generate and plot a random distribution
shinyServer(function(input,output) {

dataset <- reactive(function(){
  diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds),input$sampleSize),]
})

  output$plot <- renderPlot(function(){

p <- ggplot(dataset(),aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y))+geom_point()

if(input$color != 'None')
  p <- p + aes_string(color=input$color)

if (input$shape != 'None')
  p <- p + aes_string(shape=input$shape)

facets <- paste(input$facet_row, '~', input$facet_col)

if (facets != '. ~ .')
  p <- p + facet_grid(facets)

if (input$jitter)
  p <- p + geom_jitter()

if (input$smooth)
  p <- p + geom_smooth()

print(p)

  })  

})
```

Comment: server.R and ui.R headers should be the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a named list to `selectInput`, the names rather than the values will then be displayed (see `?selectInput`)

In your case you could do, to create the named list:

```
newnames = paste('abc', 1:10)
axis_choices <- names(dataset)
names(axis_choices) <- newnames
```

and to pass it to the first `selectInput`:

```
 selectInput('x','X', axis_choices )
```