# ggplot2 mutate error when select variable from uploaded dataset in R shinydashbard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shinydashboard

I am trying to plot using `ggplot` in R shiny. I want to upload data and any variable can be used for plotting. I am trying to keep `aes()` dynamically. I tried a few examples [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635673/select-a-variable-from-drop-down-and-pass-it-as-an-argument-in-reactiveplot-in-r), but dint work for me. Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Upload data File',
                accept=c('text/csv','.xlsx', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv'))),
      mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput('contents')
      )
    ),
  tabPanel("First Type",
           pageWithSidebar(
             headerPanel('Visualization of Dengue Cases'),
             sidebarPanel(
               
              
               selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', ""),
               selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = "")
               
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput('MyPlot')
             )
           )
  )
  )
  
       
       
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data <- reactive({ 
    req(input$file1) 
    
    inFile <- input$file1 
    
    
    df <- read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath,  sep=""), 1)
    
    
    
    
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])
    
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data()
  },options = list(pageLength = 10, width="100%", scrollX = TRUE))
  
  
  output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    select_quo <- quo(input$MyPlot_select)
    
    data %>%
      mutate(user_input = !!select_quo) %>%
      ggplot(aes(fill=user_input,  y=user_input, x= user_input)) + 
      geom_bar( stat="identity")
    
    })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can use any data set, such as [Diamond dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/shivam2503/diamonds/version/1).
Also kindly help in allowing all types of formats `(.csv, .txt,.xls)` of data. As of now, only `.xls` is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You use `data` instead of `data()` in the `renderPlot`
2. There is no input `input$MyPlot_select`.
3. Using `quo` and `!!` will not give the desired result. Instead you could simply use the `.data` pronoun if your column names are strings.
4. Add `req` at the beginning of `renderPlot`.

This said your `renderPlot` should look like so:

```
output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$xcol, input$ycol)

    x <- input$xcol
    y <- input$ycol
    fill <- input$xcol
    
    ggplot(data(), aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], fill=.data[[fill]])) + 
      geom_col()
  })
```

For the second part of your question. To make your app work for different types of input files you could get the file extension using e.g. `tools::file_ext` and use the result in `switch` statement.

Full reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Upload data File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv", ".xlsx",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv"
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("contents")
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "First Type",
    pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel("Visualization of Dengue Cases"),
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("xcol", "X Variable", ""),
        selectInput("ycol", "Y Variable", "", selected = "")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("MyPlot")
      )
    )
  )
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)

    inFile <- input$file1

    type <- tools::file_ext(inFile$name)
    
    filename <- inFile$datapath
    
    df <- switch(type,
                 "xlsx" = read_excel(filename),
                 "csv" = read_csv(filename),
                 "tsv" = read_tsv(filename))
    
    updateSelectInput(session,
      inputId = "xcol", label = "X Variable",
      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)
    )
    updateSelectInput(session,
      inputId = "ycol", label = "Y Variable",
      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2]
    )

    return(df)
  })

  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
      data()
    }, options = list(pageLength = 10, width = "100%", scrollX = TRUE))

  output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$xcol, input$ycol)

    x <- input$xcol
    y <- input$ycol
    fill <- input$xcol
    
    ggplot(data(), aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], fill=.data[[fill]])) + 
      geom_col()
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]